# Is there another way to browse user controls in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms. 
I don't know if the term "browse" is right to use in this case or not.

I have `Form1` with 3 `buttons` ( `buttonA` , `buttonB` and `buttonc`) in it.
I linked `buttonA` with a user control which contains 20 `buttons` and each one of those 20 `buttons` is linked to a user control which contains 10 `buttons` each of which does an action which it is clicked, also same thing applies to `buttonB` and `buttonC` . Now I configured user controls visibility when `button` clicked . For example:

Click `buttonA` user control1 with 20 `buttons` show up, click one of those 20 `buttons` another user control show up with 10 `buttons`.

What I am trying to do is something like browsing windows folders but in this way I will end up having too many user controls and it is confusing and I feel this is not the correct way of doing it. Can anyone please help me if there is another way to do taht? Thank you

What I am trying to do is: I click on

Comment: Do these user controls contain only buttons or also other kind of controls?

Comment: What is a business goal that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Michał Komorowski . only buttons

Comment: @Michał Komorowski. I am building POS system where I need to browse products because one product has sub products

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems to be ideal to use [TreeView](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=treeview+contorl+winforms) control. This controls displays a hierarchy of items, in your case a hierarchy of products and subprodcuts. A user of your application will be able to expand/collapse nodes as he/she want just by clicking a node. It is much more intuitive and readable than pressing buttons.

For example you can easily achieve the following icons:

[image]

You can also associate icons with nodes, change their background or foreground etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control may fit your needs. It can display a lot of items in different forms (for your task consider using `View.LargeIcon` or `View.Tile` for `ListView.View` property). It also supports groups that may be useful for building POS system.